# Does high regression coefficient for Principal components that don't explain much variance imply that my data is not a good predictor?

Tags: linear-regression, pca

There isn't much to add to the question.
Essentially i had some data that I reduced to 4 principal components, the first two components of which explain 99% of the variance in my data. 
Upon building a linear regression model using these 4 components, the coefficients for component 3 and 4 is significantly higher (by an order of 20) in magnitude than the components 1 and 2.

Without having to look at accuracy of the model, is this information sufficient to conclude that my data is a very weak linear predictor of the dependent variable?

Answer (score 1):

The variance of the data is just that, variance. Imagine I'm trying to predict y from x1 and x2, and the true underlying model is y = x1 + e, where e~N(0,.001) and x1~N(0,.01), and x2 is drawn independently from N(0,1). There is significantly more variance in x2, but it is useless in predicting y, where x1 would be an extremely good predictor.

EDIT:
We can implement this in R.

`e = rnorm(100,0,.001)
x1 = rnorm(100,0,.01)
x2 = rnorm(100,0,1)
y = x1 + e
x = data.frame(cbind(x1,x2))
pca1 = prcomp(x)
pca1
summary(pca1)
model <- lm(y ~ ., data=data.frame(pca1$x))`

Here is what our PCA looks like

`PC1           PC2
x1 0.0003702204 -0.9999999315
x2 0.9999999315  0.0003702204`
`Importance of components:
                          PC1     PC2
Standard deviation     1.0466 0.01098
Proportion of Variance 0.9999 0.00011
Cumulative Proportion  0.9999 1.00000`

So component PC1 represents 99.99% of our variance. Wow it must be a good predictor! Let's look at our model.

`Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = data.frame(pca1$x))`

`Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)

(Intercept) 7.589e-04  1.017e-04   7.463 3.64e-11 ***
PC1         3.561e-05  1.035e-04   0.344    0.732

PC2         1.002e+00  1.039e-02  96.424  < 2e-16 ***`

Oh. It turns out it's useless for prediction.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you elaborate a little as far as a Principal Components' representation of data is concerned?
While i understand variance is a measure of the spread of the data, isn't a good measure of the validity of a principal component the amount of variance that it explains?

Comment: Edited with some working code to try to better explain.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site!

In short - yes, it is fair to say that components 1 and 2 are weaker linear predictors of your target.

PCA converts a set of possibly correlated variables into a set of linearly uncorrelated variables - it's a dimension reduction technique to weed out correlated features - and involves only the predictor variables.

It is perfectly reasonable to see that the principal components are not strong predictors of the target response, as they were formed without a view (i.e. independently) of the target response.

Comment: Ah but can i extend this to say that my predictor variables are likely very weak predictors of the target variable?

Comment: I don't believe you can infer that, since each predictor is essentially a function of the principal components - e.g. predictor_m = f(prin_comp_1, prin_comp_2,..., prin_comp_n) - so one weak principal component does not mean the predictor is weak.